# shutdown with APC UPS

Tags: power-management, shutdown, ups

I'm a beginner of Linux/Ubuntu and I need your help.

Do I need to purchase PowerShuteNetworkShutdown(PCNS)to shutodown Ubuntu servers with APC UPS (Smart-UPS RT 6000/SURTD6000RMXLJP3U) ?

*Ubuntsu 16.04.2

I have read some documents and I suppose that PCNS is not required.

In my understanding, APCUPSD is used usually.

Best Regards,